# cloudformation validation returns: Invalid template resource property

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Consider this part of a cloud formation template:

```
# VPC
    myVPC:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.99.99.0/24

# Security group

    http_sec_group:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
      Properties: 
        GroupName: http_in
        GroupDescription: "Allow http traffic inbound"
        VpcId: !Ref myVPC
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - ToPort: 80
            IpProtocol: tcp
```

Validating it returns this error:

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Invalid template resource property 'myVPC'

The syntax looks correct, but why does the reference return an error?

Comment: I am not using quotes for my yml file: Type: AWS::EC2::VPC. Is the yml formatted properly?

Comment: The template which you have shared looks okay. It will be helpful if you can share the whole template.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "Invalid Template Resource Property". This is because your complete template file may be malformed due to spacing issues and CloudFormation is considering 'myVPC' as a property of previously declared resource.

More information on this error is available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-invalid-template-resource-property/).

Also, your security group resource Logical ID is invalid as Logical IDs need to be alphanumeric. More [info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html).